# how to customise UIAlertView Message Font?

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

Simply I have a button that popUp a UIAlertView view

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"u clicked me !!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];
```

I want to change the font and the size of the message also the color of the UIAlertView?

is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think there's easy way to change the background colour. If you only want to change the font size, please have a look at this [post by Himanshu Sharma](http://blackberrymastercracks.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/how-to-change-uialertview-fontcolors.html).

I have issue with [Appirater](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/appirater) for iPhone in Landscape mode and used the code to adjust the font size and it works for me. Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: This solution worked on iOS 6(.1), but it doesn't seem to work for iOS 7 :(

Answer (score 7):

I hear of lots of people subclassing UIAlertView, but then I read this comment on [Apple's UIAlertView Class Reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

i.e. people should not be attempting to modify the elements or behavior of UIAlertView.  It's likely that behavior can change in later versions of iOS (e.g. iOS 6 or iOS 5.3 or whatever), breaking their various modifications to UIAlertView.

Anyways, to answer your question: why not try creating your own UIView that you can add as UIAlertView-like subview on top of any of your views?  That way, you'd have easy control over both the background color and the label fonts and everything.

Comment: yah, that what I thought ,there is no simple way ,creating another uiview is a good thing ,the best I can see after digging over the net.. 
I hope apple would handle it better in the upcoming IOS SDK versions 
thnx alot michael :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a late answer but you could try GRAlertView, which i find very good: [GRAlertView](https://github.com/goncz9/GRAlertView)

Comment: I tried GRAlertView on my iPhone 5 running iOS 7, it only shows the plain text title/message, all the images and fancy stuffs no longer works in iOS 7 :-(